# Detecting text outside php open tags

Tags: php

Is it possible to detect text outside php open and close tags. Most of the time there is text outside these tags as a result of typo. Since it is "syntactically" correct to have text outside these tags, php -l exits with a success

```
some random unwanted text due to a typo
<?
 //some useful code
?>
```

I want to detect that there is some text before php open tags

Comment: Could you give an example, to clarify the question somewhat. Detect how, and when?

Comment: from where to check the .php file? keep in mind that "getting" a php means you actually executing it, so take the output.

Comment: How do you differentiate "random unwanted text" from HTML for instance, or is any character that is not PHP-code to be considered as invalid? How do you want to this validation?

Comment: I do three things: (i) always start such files with a PHP tag; (ii) start it at byte zero.  (iii) Never include a trailing `?>` tag.  Its now simple to validate such files with a simple script.

Answer (score 1):

Anything outside of the PHP tag itself would likely fall into DOM level interactions in a client-side language like JavaScript, and even then once the page renders the php tags don't exist to the DOM as they are rendered in there respective HTML varations in a matter of speaking. If you wanted to to actually find something outside of `<? /*code*/ ?>` you could look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and open the file server side, but you would have to build up some form of parser logic that would look for the php tags and see if there is anything above or below (outside) of them that is out of place.

Alternatively you could also double check your work to ensure the tags are opened and closed properly and nothing is outside of them like what your looking for..

On a side note is there anything your attempting to figure out as to why you would actually want to see whats outside of the PHP tags?